# Smartsheet data into Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview, smartsheet-api

I am quite new to Smartsheet and programming using c#.  Mostly a beginner and trying to use visual studio 2013 to integrate my web application with Smartsheet.  I am currently struggling with getting a gridview control to populate with the returned data from Smartsheet(in json format).  So far, I have been able to get the json string which contains:

```
{  
   "id":4705121406871428,
   "name":"Distributors",
   "version":3,
   "totalRowCount":2,
   "accessLevel":"OWNER",
   "effectiveAttachmentOptions":[  
      "DROPBOX",
      "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
      "BOX_COM",
      "FILE"
   ],
   "ganttEnabled":false,
   "dependenciesEnabled":false,
   "permalink":"https://app.smartsheet.com/b/home?lx=xlJ7OtqknyOndgOnClj4qg",
   "createdAt":"2015-06-22T16:55:02+10:00",
   "modifiedAt":"2015-06-23T14:17:47+10:00",
   "columns":[  
      {  
         "id":3238895438587780,
         "index":0,
         "title":"id",
         "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
         "primary":true,
         "width":150
      },
      {  
         "id":7742495065958276,
         "index":1,
         "title":"distName",
         "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
         "width":150
      },
      {  
         "id":2112995531745156,
         "index":2,
         "title":"agency",
         "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
         "width":150
      },
      {  
         "id":6616595159115652,
         "index":3,
         "title":"profile",
         "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
         "width":150
      }
   ],
   "rows":[  
      {  
         "id":3999757174630276,
         "rowNumber":1,
         "expanded":true,
         "createdAt":"2015-06-23T11:05:26+10:00",
         "modifiedAt":"2015-06-23T14:17:47+10:00",
         "cells":[  
            {  
               "columnId":3238895438587780,
               "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
               "value":1.0,
               "displayValue":"1"
            },
            {  
               "columnId":7742495065958276,
               "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
               "value":"ABS",
               "displayValue":"ABS"
            },
            {  
               "columnId":2112995531745156,
               "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
               "value":"ShedsRus",
               "displayValue":"ShedsRus"
            },
            {  
               "columnId":6616595159115652,
               "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
               "value":"OK",
               "displayValue":"OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":8503356802000772,
         "rowNumber":2,
         "siblingId":3999757174630276,
         "expanded":true,
         "createdAt":"2015-06-23T11:05:26+10:00",
         "modifiedAt":"2015-06-23T14:17:47+10:00",
         "cells":[  
            {  
               "columnId":3238895438587780,
               "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
               "value":2.0,
               "displayValue":"2"
            },
            {  
               "columnId":7742495065958276,
               "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
               "value":"Barns",
               "displayValue":"Barns"
            },
            {  
               "columnId":2112995531745156,
               "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
               "value":"BarnsRus",
               "displayValue":"BarnsRus"
            },
            {  
               "columnId":6616595159115652,
               "type":"TEXT_NUMBER",
               "value":"OK",
               "displayValue":"OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This string looks to contain too much information such as id's, and types etc...
All i want is my column names, and their associated data.
Then, display this info as a gridview control.

This is my json request:

```
        string sURL;
        sURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/4705121406871428";

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        wrGETURL.ContentType = "application/json";
        wrGETURL.Method = "GET";
        wrGETURL.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ******************";

        Stream objStream;
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

        string jsonResult = objReader.ReadToEnd();
```

If anyone can provide some guidance to get this working for me, it would be greatly appreciated...please excuse my total ignorance on this topic...complete newb here!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the response from the Smartsheet API there is a `columns` object, which is made up of an array of the columns from your sheet. Loop over this array to get the column titles and the column IDs.

Then, go through the `rows` object and loop over each row. For each row you'll want to loop over the array of `cells` for that row and output the `displayValue`. Make sure that each `columnId` for the cell matches the `id` of the column you are printing, because if you have a blank cell in Smartsheet, no cell object will be returned by the Smartsheet API.

You can find more information about the Smartsheet API [here](https://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation). And, If you haven't already done so, I would also recommend checking out the [C# SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk) for the Smartsheet API.